# datacontext in johnpapa angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In a recent project, we opted for johnpapa angularjs framework for a web app. Now, we want our pages to interact with web api located on the server. So, for this I have googled a bit and found that there are two approaches one is factory and other is service. And the datacontext located in johnpapa angularjs framework is a factory. So, now it looks like that all the calls we going to make to our webapi's needs to be implemented in teh datacontext factory. Which seems little messy imo. And what I want is to create a seperate file for each service/factory i.e. userSvc.js, orderSvc.js

So, is it a good approach to split the functions in different service/factory according to their logical separation. And, second thing is that do i need to create service or factory for calling webapis.

Comment: What is John Papa AngularJS framework?

Comment: It is a framework to built SPA. www.johnpapa.net/

Comment: It is just AngularJS, it is built by Google.